# In call Mute button sound. Can it be STOPPED?

Tags: audio, phone-app, mute

Is there a way to set the MUTE button (the one on the in-call phone menu) to NOT make a sound when pressed. For instance, when I'm in conference calls on my GalaxyS4, and want to mute my microphone, I press the mute button which makes a "drop" sound. Which I do frequently when I am not speaking. Soon after, a colleague of mine sent me an instant message and informed me that they could all hear the "drop" sound every time I pressed the darned thing..

Is there any way to make it not do that??